# How to change from dual-boot to only ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, partition, windows, dual-boot

I have both Windows and Ubuntu 14.04 on my computer, and I'm having some trouble. The Windows partition doesn't actually work at all, and the Ubuntu partition is getting buggy. I'm f.ex. having trouble downloading packages etc., and I can't seem to find out why.

Since I haven't used the Windows partition for almost 3 years now, I'm thinking that it's completely unnecessary. I also have a laptop at my job which has Windows. I would like to only have Ubuntu, and also perhaps an upgraded version, not necessarirly 14.04.

Is this something I could do myself? I haven't enabled the dual-booting myself. I don't need to load files from a backup, as the files I have there are all small enough to just backup to my cloud storing service. I'm hoping that this is something that isn't too risky to attempt by myself, but of course it's important that the computer survives an eventual attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't worried about losing any / all the files from either partition, you can set up an Ubuntu-only environment extremely easily: simply download the Ubuntu ISO ([here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)), and select "Erase Everything and Install" when prompted.

If you want to keep everything on your Ubuntu partition, that's not too difficult ***IF*** your Ubuntu partition is set up with LVM. If so, you can do this from the Ubuntu Live Disk (select "Try Ubuntu" when booting from the Ubuntu Installation CD) and launching GParted. You can then delete your Windows partition and then resize your Ubuntu partition to consume it's space.

As for the issues you mentioned with packages not updating properly, all that I can really recommend is to Google whatever error it gave you.